Backslash causes errors on variables
If I try setting a variable that has a backslash it causes an error.
if %errorlevel% equ 3 set crntPath=%crntPath%!directories[%%n]!

I simply want to add Acer\ to C:\Users\Program Files (x86)\
yet this gives me an error saying:
\!directories[%n]! was unexpected at this time.

I do not understand why it does this, I can add Acer\ to C:\Users\Program Files\, but not C:\Users\Program Files (x86)\.
Here is the full source code:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set crntPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\
set dontrepeat=0
:getFiles
for /l %%n in (1,1,250) do (
    set "files[%%n]="
    set "directories[%%n]="
)
set pointing=1
set /a count=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%crntPath%" /B /AD') do (
    set directories[!count!]=%%i
    set /a count+=1
)
set oldcount=%count%
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%crntPath%" /B /A-D') do (
    set files[!count!]=%%i
    set /a count+=1
)
set directories[0]=..
goto main
:outputFiles
cls
set dontrepeat=1
echo %crntPath%
for /l %%n in (0,1,%count%) do (
    if "!directories[%%n]!" neq "" (
        if %pointing% equ %%n (
            if %pointing% equ 0 (
                if %errorlevel% equ 3 for %%D in ("%crntPath:~0,-1%") do set crntPath=%%~dpD&goto getFiles
            ) else (
                if %errorlevel% equ 3 set crntPath=%crntPath%!directories[%%n]!
                rem error???
            )
            echo [DIR] !directories[%%n]!
        ) else (
            echo !directories[%%n]!
        )
    )
)
for /l %%n in (%oldcount%,1,%count%) do (
    if "!files[%%n]!" neq "" (
        if %pointing% equ %%n (
            if %errorlevel% equ 3 "%crntPath%!files[%%n]!"
            echo [FILE] !files[%%n]!
        ) else (
            echo !files[%%n]!
        )
    )
)
goto main

:main
if %dontrepeat% equ 0 goto outputFiles
choice /c zxc /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 set /a pointing-=1 & if !pointing! lss 0 (set /a pointing=%count%-1)
if %errorlevel% equ 2 set /a pointing+=1 & if !pointing! geq %count% (set /a pointing=0)
set dontrepeat=0
goto outputFiles

I've tried switching all backslashes to forward slashes yet it still doesnt work.

It happens because of the parentheses in your variable value. But the problem could theoretically be any special symbol that is offensive to a batch script. Better to declare with double quotes:-
set crntPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\"

Of course, you'll have to modify your script to accomodate this particular change. (For eg. dir %crntPath% /b /a-d )
If you want to add append something to it, you could do :-
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%crntPath%) do set crntPath="%%~i!directories[%%n]!"

Using double-quotes is generally advisable for all paths especially if storing them in variables.

Best practice is to not include quotes as part of the value of a variable. But, you should use quotes to surround the assignment of a variable. Then use quotes around the full path of any file or path reference.
